# How do I know when to end a game of Vast & Starlit?

Tags: pacing, vast-and-starlit

*[Vast & Starlit](https://dig1000holes.wordpress.com/vast-starlit/)* has beautifully simple rules, but I sometimes find it hard to choose when to bring the game to climax and then conclusion.

How can I know when to end on a cliffhanger? A point of group resolution? A fiery death?

The mini-game *[What is a Roleplaying Game?](https://dig1000holes.wordpress.com/what-is-a-roleplaying-game/)* has a great condition for ending, and I think I'm grasping for something similar to apply to *Vast & Starlit*.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.se! Please take a look at the [tour]; it's a useful introduction to the site. I gave this an edit to make it ask more about a presumed technique ("how do I") rather than seem to ask for opinions ("should I"), as our site format handles people offering pure opinion not-at-all well. Nice first question, and again, welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Vast & Starlit doesn't have rules for this, you'll have to decide on your own how to pace the game and reach a conclusion.

One approach you might take is to consider the questions you answer at the beginning of the game. If any of those answers lead you into troublesome situations or create issues, you could end the game when all of those initial situations have been resolved and the issues have been dealt with.

Another solution would be to consider the text at the top-left of the rules card, which states that you are "seeking a place to hide, a place of peace, a place to call home..." If you have found such a place, (or definitively failed to,) that's likely to be a good time to stop.

Regardless, remember that it's up to all the players together to decide when the game ends, so you should make sure everyone is on the same page about what sort of scope you're all aiming for. Likewise, it's not up to you alone to set the pacing or level of tension. Talk to your fellow players and find out what everyone wants or expects - or if you prefer, let this stuff arise organically and don't worry about it too much.

(As for cliffhangers, the game text is clear: If a focus player attempts something that another player calls out as Difficult, Dangerous or Both, you end the scene on a cliffhanger.)

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Thanks for your answer and I hope you stay around.  Please take a look at our [help] and [tour] when you have time, and I look forward to more questions and answers from you on this interesting and underappreciated system.